# ec2_instance_facts botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

When I'm trying to run my ansible playbook towards my EC2 machine on AWS & collect some facts using ec2_instance_facts module. I'm getting the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

**Aws CLI:**

```
[ansible@control aws]$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.81 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.12.71
```

**Ansible:**

```
[ansible@control aws]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.7.5
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Oct 30 2018, 23:45:53) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
[ansible@control aws]$
```

I did add my credentials using aws configure

```
[ansible@control aws]$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************SGWA]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************kZwS]:
Default region name [ca-central]:
Default output format [None]:
[ansible@control aws]$
```

and it's getting saved properly:

```
[ansible@control aws]$ aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************SGWA shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************kZwS shared-credentials-file
    region               ca-central              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

I checked credentials

```
ansible@control .aws]$ cat credentials
    [default]
    aws_access_key_id = **********************GWA
    aws_secret_access_key = ***************************kZwS
```

I also checked config

```
[ansible@control .aws]$ cat config
[default]
region = ca-central
```

My account ansible has `AmazonEC2FullAccess`

Not quite sure what I'm missing here! Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try setting up credentials as explained at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_aws.html#authentication and see if it helps

Comment: Are you running ansible with `delegate_to: localhost` for that `ec2_instance_facts:` module, because if not, ansible will run that module on the remote machine, which presumably does not have the same `~/.aws/credentials` as does the `ansible@control` machine in your examples

Comment: got the same error and i have no delegate_to in my ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best solution is not to use Ansible with AWS directly, as packages are not well marinated. Try and use another project like terraform for managing AWS and use Ansible for automating tasks.